# Batch Script to check if Zip file extracted or not

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch scripting and trying to write a script which will search the zip files inside a folder and extract if exists using 7-Zip. These two are working fine but i am trying to implement a logic where i need to update the log file which will have the entries which zip file got extracted and which got failed. Can someone help me here as when i tried to append log after extracting its showing all the entries present inside the zip files which i dont want. Below is script.

```
    @ECHO OFF
    SET LookForFile="C:\test\Software00*.*"

    :CheckForFile
    IF EXIST %LookForFile% GOTO RunELK

    #ECHO TIMEOUT /T 20 >nul

    GOTO CheckForFile

    :RunELK
    ECHO RunELK for this file : %LookForFile%
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "C:\test\Software00*.*" -oC:\test >> C:\test\LOG1.LOG
```

Comment: Check out the `-bb` option (log level; since version 15) of `7z.exe`; perhaps you are also interested in the SuperUser post [How to write error status for command line 7-zip in variable (or, instead, in text file)](http://superuser.com/q/519114)...

Comment: I tried above but again it seems giving me all the extracted file names which typically hard for me to read as i have lot of zip files.Is it possible to have entries for only the zip file names not the extracted ones.